# How do I delay an array callback using async/await in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to put a delay between each iteration in a loop using async await. I've got a helper sleep function:

```
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

And this is correctly waiting between each loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('waiting')
    await sleep(1000)
}
```

However, this is not waiting between each loop:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(async () => {
    console.log('waiting')
    await sleep(1000)
});
```

How can I modify the forEach code block to behave as the regular for loop block with delays between each iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Since you're using a modern version of ECMAScript (with `async`/`await`), you probably don't want to use `.forEach`. It was from before the language had proper iterators, which you can now use with `for (let/const value of array)` (instead of a for-in loop as you have, which are also more-or-less obsolete).

Comment: To make this work, `forEach` itself would have to `await` the promise returned by the callback. But `.forEach` completely ignores the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You *could theoretically* build up a promise chain, thats slightly more beautiful with `reduce`, but the same pattern can also be done with `forEach`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(async (previous) => {
  await previous;
  console.log('waiting')
  await sleep(1000)
});
```

But ... why not just use a `for` loop?

Comment: Actually I was looking to do what you suggested with reduce...I don't know why I used forEach in my example

And no real good reason to use reduce over a for loop other than it being slightly cleaner for my purpose so I was just wondering if there was an easy way to achieve this that I was overlooking

Comment: This solution will use tons of memory for a large array. Only pointing that out for the questioner.

Comment: @andrew I can't think of a situation were a forEach would be "cleaner" than a for though ...

Comment: To clarify I meant that using a reduce would be cleaner than a for loop. I shouldn't have mentioned forEach that was a bad example (I was just randomly pulling out a looping function with a callback).

Comment: But yes thanks for the comments, I ended up running out of memory as you guys suggested might happen, so I'll go with a regular for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer methods rather than loops (which I usually do just aesthetically) you could pull in a third party module I maintain called [`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af).

Among other things, it provides an [asynchronous-friendly sequential forEach](https://async-af.js.org/AsyncAF#forEachAF):

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

AsyncAF([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).series.forEach(async () => {
  console.log('waiting');
  await sleep(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/async-af@7.0.14/index.js"></script>
```

Of course, you could also just use a simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  for (const _ of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    console.log('waiting');
    await sleep(1000);
  }
})();
```

As for *why* `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't work the way you'd expect, take this overly simplified implementation ([here's a fuller one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)):

```js
const forEach = (arr, fn) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // nothing is awaiting this function call
    fn(arr[i], i, arr);
    // i is then synchronously incremented and the next function is called
  }
  // return undefined
};

forEach([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], async () => {
  console.log('waiting');
  await delay(1000);
});
```

As you can see, `Array.prototype.forEach` synchronously calls the given callback function on each element. That's why you see all five `waiting` logs almost immediately. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/50973858) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `for...of` is the way to go.

However if you die hard want a `.forEach` method, you can do something like this:

```js
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

/* Create your own async forEach */
Array.prototype.asyncForEach = async function asyncForEach(callback, ctx){
  const len = this.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
    await callback.call(ctx, this[i], i, this);
};

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].asyncForEach(async function(n){
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log(n);
});
```